# TikZ: specify label position in edge style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-graphs

I am writing many small graphs, using Ti*k*Z's graphs library, which often include loops. I do not like the way the default `loop left` or `loop right` options look, so I have made my own style, called `ll` here.

That is fine, but when I provide a label using the quotes syntax, I have to manually place it, which isn't necessary with `loop left`. How can I specify in the preamble where labels should be placed?

**Update**: Gonzalo Medina's answer puts the labels on the proper side.
I would also like them to be closer to the edge, like when I use `left=-2pt` in the code below. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\tikzset{ll/.style={in=210,out=150,distance=3mm},
dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph {a/[dot] --[ll,"1" left=-2pt] a};  What I want to see.

\tikz \graph {a/[dot] --[ll,"1"] a};  What I want to type.

\tikz \graph {a/[dot] --[loop left,"1"] a};  The `loop left' option ``knows'' what to do.

\end{document}
```

[image: Loops]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a different definition of the `ll` adjusting the `in` and `out` values:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

%\tikzset{
%  ll/.style={
%    in=210,
%    out=150,
%    distance=3mm,
%    looseness=8
%    },
%}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  ll/.style={
    in=150,
    out=210,
    loop,
    min distance=3mm,
    every node/.append style={inner xsep=1pt}
  },
  dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph {a/[dot] --[ll,"1"] a};  What I get with the \texttt{ll}a style.

\tikz \graph {a/[dot] --[loop left,"1"] a};  The \texttt{loop left} option ``knows'' what to do.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right: swapping the "in" and "out" parameters results in the label on the left side. Thanks! Ideally, I could also have the labels placed closer to the loop (as with `left=-2pt`.)

Comment: @Kundor Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works. (I ended up going with `inner xsep=.1111em`, and `inner ysep=.2666em` for the analogous up- and down-loops.